# Counting rows with the same attributes XML/SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle-sqldeveloper

Started doing some SQL/XML resently but i have the problem of doing count functions.

Lets say i have the database

```
<Root>
   <Element ATTTRIBUTE1 ="A"  ATTRIBUTE2="1" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="A"  ATTRIBUTE2="1" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="A"  ATTRIBUTE2="1" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="A" ATTRIBUTE2="1" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="A" ATTRIBUTE2="1" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="A" ATTRIBUTE2="3" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="A" ATTRIBUTE2="3" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="B" ATTRIBUTE2="3" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="B" ATTRIBUTE2="3" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="B" ATTRIBUTE2="3" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="B" ATTRIBUTE2="3" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="C" ATTRIBUTE2="4" />
   <Element ATTRIBUTE1 ="C" ATTRIBUTE2="4" />
</Root>
```

What can i write in SLQ/XML to make it count how many of each i have that have the two same attributes?  So for example i have 5 elements of with attributes A and 1, 2 attributes of A and 3 and two attributes of B and 3 and so on.

I have tried to group them but i kind of just split them up outside the root then.

Comment: Or if i can somehow when building the element add atribute 1 and 2 togheter creating, atribute3 = "A1"

Comment: **ATTRIBUTE** really should have **two** `T` in it ...